# How do you find the sum of specific items in a 2d array with a foreach loop?

Tags: python, loops, foreach, sum

I have this list:
`my_list = [('a',1), ('b',2), ('c',3)]`

How can i write a foreach loop to find the sum of 1+2+3?

Comment: What have you tried?  This is not hard.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach:

```
list = [('a',1), ('b',2), ('c',3)]

summ = 0 # variable to store sum
for i in list:
    summ = summ + i[1]

print(summ)
```

This returns `6`

Answer (score 0):

Short approach using a comprehension:

```py
items = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
print(sum(item[1] for item in items))
```

Please avoid naming your list `list`, it's the name of the list type in Python, so you're "hiding" the list type, which can cause strange bugs if you need the real `list` later.